# comapare files that are on remote directory and local directory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

I got a code on this site to download files from remote directory from the server. Now I want modify this code so it compares the files and lists that are on remote directory and not on local directory. It lists the uncommon files between remote directory and local directory . 
Is this possible?
Please help.  Thanks in Advance

```
import os
import pysftp
import socket
from stat import S_IMODE, S_ISDIR, S_ISREG

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

IP = "192.168.X.X"
myUsername = "user"
port = 22
myPassword = "password"

try:
    with pysftp.Connection(host=IP, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        try:
            r=str(socket.gethostbyaddr(IP))
            print("connection successful with "+r)


            def get_r_portable(sftp, remotedir, localdir, preserve_mtime=False):
                for entry in sftp.listdir(remotedir):
                    remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry
                    localpath = os.path.join(localdir, entry)
                    mode = sftp.stat(remotepath).st_mode
                    if S_ISDIR(mode):
                        try:
                            os.mkdir(localpath, mode=777)
                        except OSError:
                            pass
                        get_r_portable(sftp, remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime)
                    elif S_ISREG(mode):
                        sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime=preserve_mtime)


            remote_path = input("enter the remote_path: ")
            local_path = input("enter the local_path: ")

            get_r_portable(sftp, remote_path, local_path, preserve_mtime=False)
        except socket.herror:
            print("Unknown host")
except:
    print("connection failed")
```

Outcome should be the uncommon files that are present in remote directory and not in local directory.

Comment: No It's not possible. Please go through the below link. [Check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423510/comparing-local-file-with-remote-file)

Comment: @ashok knv please see the answers below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sync only the changed files from the remote directory using pysftp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459065/how-to-sync-only-the-changed-files-from-the-remote-directory-using-pysftp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def getFilesList(path):
files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    files.extend(filenames)
    return files
ServerFiles = getFilesList(Srverpath)
LocalFiles = getFilesList(Lclpath) 
fileDiffList = []
for file in ServerFiles: 
    if file in LocalFiles: 
        pass 
    else:
        fileDiffList.append(file)
```

We can get the uncommon files by using 2 separate lists.
Call getFilesList method twice by passing your server path and local file path.
At the end your 'fileDiffList' will have file names

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download new files and those which are not on your local system, use rsync. you can sync your local directory with the remote one like below:

```
rsync -a ~/dir1 username@remote_host:destination_directory
```

How use it in python:

```
import subprocess

args = ["rsync", "-av", "-e", "ssh", "user@server:/tmp/", "/home/local/Desktop/"]
subprocess.call(args)
```

you can pass `--password-file` switch and it must point to a file contains ssh passwords, or you can use ssh key.

Comment: is it applicable to python?

Comment: you can run it by Subprocess or os module.

Comment: if you are comfortable can u provide a example?

Comment: sure, edited previous answer and added simple example.

Comment: I tried but it keeps on failing. If comfortable can you apply above r sync code to my code? thanks