# Compare 2 files online in R

Tags: r

I've got a link X (pointing to a pdf file) and a link Y (pointing to a file, likely of pdf format)

I'm not sure if it is possible but what I would like is for a way to validate if the content of X and Y are exactly the same without downloading them. (content here excludes the file name)

This is relatively easy if I was to not care for efficiency. I'd simply download both files with `download.file` and compare them with `md5sum`.
However, since X and Y are vectors (2k length and growing for X, 0.5k to 1.5k lenght for Y oscillating daily) and every day I plan to check them for pairs it won't be practical.

A hybrid would be to download only X and save it on disk and then maybe filter Y for ending with ".pdf", but i'd rather avoid storing a copy of those files in the client's drive altogether.

Is there some way to validate this that i'm missing?

Comment: I think you can't without downloading, maybe related post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3423510/680068

Comment: Yea, thanks. The hash ideia is very good. Y is on trello so I don't think i'll get to hash that. What i can do is save X's hashes instead of it's links or files. Won't save me much processing but it will certainly save on disk space