# download a file directly to memory

Tags: r

I'm wondering if this is possible.
I've got a link to a pdf file and I need to get it's `MD5Sum`. ([my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63832857/compare-2-files-online-in-r?noredirect=1#comment112877455_63832857)) For that I'll need to first download it and I want to do it on the most efficient way. I'm guessing that since files are small and RAM is faster than disk the obvious path would be to store it on RAM, calculate the `MD5Sum` and throw it away.

So far I'm using this:

```
link <- "xxxxx.pdf"
download.file(link, "temp.pdf", quiet = TRUE, mode = "wb")
result <- md5sum("temp.pdf")
unlink("temp.pdf")
```

I just read about `tempfile()` and that I could use it instead of "temp.pdf" but it looks like i'd just be adding an extra line to the code.

Are there better methods to get the files?

Comment: So, you want to create a [RAM disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive)?

Comment: after reading on the topic, looks like it, but it also feels overkill. Requiring a program as well as to permanently allocate a portion of the RAM is not worth it. (for this project at least)

Comment: AFAIU, R mostly relies on the OS for file services. I don't think R can put a file into RAM directly, but I have been surprised before.

Comment: ok, thanks! Outside saving it to RAM, know of any way to improve the current code?